# Java \ Pattern - how to write a pattern that verifies the lack of a string?

Tags: java, regex

I tried from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

I have

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("agg{0}.*");
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher("agg_0_4_Jul_2010_13_32_53_759_0.csv");

if (m.matches() == true)  => true.
```

I want this to return FALSE - since it does contain agg in the string start.
In short - how to verify the lack of substring (in a positive way).
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it? I'm just curious.

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you test if m.matches() == false?

Comment: I want to build a pattern that states : "everything but.."

Answer (score 10):

#### Note on original pattern

Your original pattern contains the very peculiar `agg{0}`. It needs to be said that this pattern makes no sense. Due to the way precedence between concatenation and repetition, and the fact that `{0}` is exactly zero repetition of a pattern, this `agg{0}` is simply `ag`.

Thus, you get the following:

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("agg{0}.*");
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher("aged gouda yum yum!");
System.out.println(m.matches()); // prints "true"
```

To illustrate how repetition and concatenation interacts, and how sometimes grouping is required, here are some more examples:

```
System.out.println(  "hahaha".matches("ha{3}")    ); // prints "false"
System.out.println(  "haaa".matches("ha{3}")      ); // prints "true"
System.out.println(  "hahaha".matches("(ha){3}")  ); // prints "true"
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [Round Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### On negating a matching

The original specification isn't very clear, but here are some basic facts:

- The [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class has the following simple non-regex methods:

  - [`boolean startsWith(String prefix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)
  - [`boolean endsWith(String suffix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29)
  - [`boolean contains(CharSequence s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- You can negate a boolean using the `!` unary `boolean` complement operator

  - See also: [JLS 15.15.6 Logical Complement Operator !](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.15.6)

Here are some simple examples:

```
System.out.println(   "Hello world!".startsWith("Hell")  ); // "true"
System.out.println(   "By nightfall".endsWith("all")     ); // "true"
System.out.println(   "Heaven".contains("joy")           ); // "false"

System.out.println( ! "Hello world!".startsWith("Hell")  ); // "false"
System.out.println( ! "By nightfall".endsWith("all")     ); // "false"
System.out.println( ! "Heaven".contains("joy")           ); // "true"
```

---

#### On negative lookaround

If the combination of Java's logical complement and `String`'s non-regex predicate checks don't work for you, you can use negative lookarounds to negate a match on a pattern.

Generally speaking, if you want to negate what `^pattern$` matches, and for some reason you need this done in the regex itself, you can match on `^(?!pattern$).*` instead (perhaps using the single-line mode so the dot matches everything).

Here's an example of matching `a*b*`, and negating it using negative lookahead:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "aaabb",
        "abc",
        "bba",
        "aaaa",
        "bbbbbb",
        "what is this?",
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.printf("[%s] %s - %s %n",
            test,
            test.matches("a*b*"),
            test.matches("(?!a*b*$).*")
        );          
    }
```

The above prints:

```
[aaabb] true - false 
[abc] false - true 
[bba] false - true 
[aaaa] true - false 
[bbbbbb] true - false 
[what is this?] false - true
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

#### Related questions

- [Regex to match 1234, 1324, 2341 (all permutations of {1,2,3,4})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101366/regex-to-match-1234-1324-2341-all-permutations-of-1-2-3-4)
- [Checking if every substring of four zeros is followed by at least four ones using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077566/how-can-i-check-if-every-substring-of-four-zeros-is-followed-by-at-least-four-one/3080023#3080023)
- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)
- [Why is negation of a regex needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890873/why-is-negation-of-a-regex-needed)

---

#### Going back to the question

If you insist on using negative lookarounds, then you can use one of these two patterns depending on what you actually need:

- `^(?!agg).*$` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/bk4iccZYS1))

  - This matches strings that doesn't start with `agg`
- `^(?!.*agg).*$` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/zKxnFsj9QK))

  - This matches strings that doesn't contain `agg`

Answer (score 1):

Simple alternative:

```
if (!csv.startsWith("agg") {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [`contains`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) , it's a method of `String`