# Match all Strings without the word "authorize" in them

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java \ Pattern - how to write a pattern that verifies the lack of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177926/java-pattern-how-to-write-a-pattern-that-verifies-the-lack-of-a-string)

How can I match all strings without the word "authorize" in them via regular expressions?  I tried `*(authorize){0}*` to no avail.

Comment: you should invest an hour and read the tutorials, e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ ; your pattern makes no sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
/^(?!.*authorize).*/
```

This uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that the overall pattern will match only if the expression "authorize" cannot match anywhere in the input.

Comment: Most modern regex engines implement positive and negative lookahead assertions.