# Regular expression to search for a string1 that is never followed by string2

Tags: python, regex, expression

How to construct a regular expression search pattern to find string1 that is not followed by string2 (immediately or not)?

For for instance, if string1="MAN" and string2="PN", example search results would be:

```
"M": Not found
"MA": Not found
"MAN": Found
"BLAH_MAN_BLEH": Found
"MAN_PN": Not found
"BLAH_MAN_BLEH_PN": Not found
"BLAH_MAN_BLEH_PN_MAN": Not found
```

Ideally, a one-linear search, instead of doing a second search for string2.

PS: Language being used is Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use `MAN(?!.*PN)`. This matches `MAN` and uses negative lookahead to make sure that it's not followed by `PN` ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/BP0T80KVsR)).

Given `MAN_PN_MAN_BLEH`, the above pattern will find the second `MAN`, since it's not followed by `PN`. If you want to validate the entire string and make sure that there's no `MAN.*PN`, then you can use something like `^(?!.*MAN.*PN).*MAN.*$` ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/QtlvGlfisu)).

#### References

- [regular-expressios.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

#### Related questions

- [How can I check if every substring of four zeros is followed by at least four ones using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077566/how-can-i-check-if-every-substring-of-four-zeros-is-followed-by-at-least-four-one/3080023#3080023)

---

#### Non-regex option

If the strings are to be matched literally, then you can also check for indices of substring occurrences.

In Python, `find` and `rfind` return lowest and highest index of substring occurrences respectively.

So to make sure that `string1` occurs but never followed by `string2`, and both returns `-1` if the string is not found, so it looks like you can just test for this condition:

```
string.rfind(s, string2) < string.find(s, string1)
```

This compares the leftmost occurrence of `string1` and the rightmost occurrence of `string2`.

- If neither occurs, both are `-1`, and result is `false`
- If `string1` occurs, but `string2` doesn't, then result is `true` as expected
- If both occurs, then the rightmost `string2` must be to the left of the leftmost `string1`

  - That is, no `string1` is ever followed by `string2`

#### API links

- [`find`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find)
- [`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.rfind)

Comment: In the intended example, it would not be a match.  So, if string1 occurs, but is ever followed by string2, it would negate the find.

Comment: @apalopohapa: I'm still not sure if I get this 100% correct, so feel free to edit the question later with more examples and/or unaccept my answer if it fails you on some input. I will come back to this several hours from now and see if there are any unresolved issues.

Comment: @apalopohapa: Also, I think `MAN(?!.*P(?=.*N?))` is just `MAN(?!.*P)`, which then opens up possibilities of `MAN[^P]*` etc. The more information we have, the better answers we can give.

Comment: @apalopohapa: I think `MAN(?!.*P(?=.*N))` is just `MAN(?!.*P.*N)`

Comment: -1 Don't use $ to match end of string, use \Z. "." doesn't match newline by default; you need to use the re.DOTALL flag.